# 'Select Java Application' After Running SpringBoot Project

Tags: java, spring-boot, eclipse

[What pops up when I try to run my SpringBoot project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvX8c.png)

I honestly have no clue what happened, I was running all the projects from my class . Now it wont allow me to run the project I select to be ran as a SpringBoot project.

I typically just right click my project, go down to run as, then select SpringBoot !

Now whenever I want to do that, it wants me to select another application and I am clueless

The photo I attached is the screen that pops up when I try to run a project

For my projects to run as they did before !

Comment: *How* are you trying to run this project *now*? What does that class look like? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask